# Less - saturate() without affecting hsvvalue

Tags: css, colors, less

Let's take a look at the color #a94442 hsl(1, 44%, 46%):

[image: Color #a94442]

Now, if I execute saturate(#a94442, 100%) in less I get #eb0500 hsl(1, 100%, 46%) which looks like this:

[image: Color #eb0500]

Now, if you take a look at the color picker, the color moved horizontally, AND vertically. I want to only move the color horizontally. That means that the lightness in HSL will not be maintained, but instead the value in HSL/HSB will. The color that I want to be able to calculate with less is #a80300 hsl(1, 100%, 33%):

[image: Color #a80300]

So, just to recap.

- What I start with: `#a94442 hsl(1,  44%, 46%) hsv(1,  61%, 66%)`
- What I get:           `#eb0500 hsl(1, 100%, 46%) hsv(1, 100%, 92%)`
- What I want:        `#a80300 hsl(1, 100%, 33%) hsv(1, 100%, 66%)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

`hsv(hsvhue(#a94442), 100%, hsvvalue(#a94442))`

The above will yield `#a90300 hsl(1, 100%, 33%) hsv(1, 100%, 66%)`:

[image: Color #a90300]

P.S. In my original post, I got the target color (#a80300) wrong. #a90300 is the right color. Photoshop just messed up somehow. If you look closely the Red in the RGB is off by one point with #a80300.

Comment: Just in case, I hope you do realize that HSL means Hue/Saturation/Lightness so to get `hsl(1, 100%, 33%)` from `hsl(1%, 44%, 46%)` you need two functions, i.e.: `lighten(saturate(hsl(1, 44%, 46%), (100% - 44%)), (33% - 46%));`.

Comment: >"If you look closely the Red in the RGB is off by one point with #a80300" - That's only because all those values are rounded to integers (for instance the real HSL of `#a94442` is `hsl(1.16504854, 43.82978723%, 46.07843137%)` so +/-1 drift is often expected since these rounded color representations are not strictly equal.